# How to remove rows from a data frame that have special character (any character except alphabet and numbers)

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, preprocessing, dataframe

How to remove rows from a data frame that have special character (any character except alphabet and numbers)
I have some unwanted labels which seems to be useless but I want to remove them, this are in column[0] (labels) of my dataframe.
What is easiest way to remove the rows with special character in their label column (column[0]) (for instance: ab!, #, !d) from dataframe

For instance in  2d dataframe similar to below, I would like to delete the rows whose `column= label` contain some specific characters (such as blank, !, ", $, #NA, FG@)

[image: example of dataframe]

Comment: Instead of image can you paste actual data??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **regular expression** to clean your data. Below I have compiled an almost complete list of functions that one uses frequently when cleaning text data.

```
1.) Remove URL
def remove_URL(headline_text):
    url = re.compile(r'https?://\S+|www\.\S+')
    return url.sub(r'', headline_text)

train['headline_text'] = train['headline_text'].apply(remove_URL)

2.) Remove HTML tags (<..>)
def remove_html(headline_text):
    html=re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return html.sub(r'',headline_text)

train['headline_text'] = train['headline_text'].apply(remove_html)

3.) Removing Pictures/Tags/Symbols/Emojis
def remove_emojis(data):
    emoj = re.compile("["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
        u"\U00002500-\U00002BEF"  # chinese char
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
        u"\U00010000-\U0010ffff"
        u"\u2640-\u2642" 
        u"\u2600-\u2B55"
        u"\u200d"
        u"\u23cf"
        u"\u23e9"
        u"\u231a"
        u"\ufe0f"  # dingbats
        u"\u3030"
                      "]+", re.UNICODE)
    return re.sub(emoj, '', data)
train['headline_text'] = train['headline_text'].apply(remove_emoji)

4.) Removing Punctuation
def remove_punct(headline_text):
    table=str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)
    return headline_text.translate(table)
train['headline_text'] = train['headline_text'].apply(remove_punct)

5.) Remove everything except strings
corpus = []

for i in range(0 ,len(data1)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', data1['features'][i])
    corpus.append(review)
```

**EDIT BASED ON THE COMMENT**

If you want to remove the rows with special characters then this might help:

```
# select and then merge rows
# with special characters
print(df[df.label.str.contains(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z]')])
 
# drop the rows
print(df.drop(df[df.label.str.contains(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z]')].index))
```

Another thing you can do besides dropping the rows would be to convert the non ASCII characters in ASCII. That way you do not loose information. I do not know if it will work in your case but give it a try and lemme know how it goes:

```
string_with_nonASCII = "àa string withé fuünny charactersß."
encoded_string = string_with_nonASCII.encode("ascii", "ignore")
decode_string = encoded_string.decode()
print(decode_string)
```

The above code will output `a string with funny characters.`

**Cheers!**

Comment: thanks spectre but I would like to remove the whole rows in a dataframe which column label contains specific character

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the changes

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
index = []
#this list is used to store index of rows having characters except alphabets and numbers
for i in range(len(df['Tables label__1'])):
    try:
        if(regex.search(df['Tables label__1'][i]) != None):
            index.append(i)
    except:
        index.append(i)
df = df.drop(index)
#dropping all the indexes at once
```

**I hope this code will help you with your task!!!**